# Projection using MongoEngine Raw-Query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Does anyone know, how I can implement the following MongoDB query using a MongoEngine Raq-Query?

```
db.getCollection('subscribers').find({
    '_id': ObjectId("579e60b0c525fd2037e8dd31"),
    'history.content.read_process_msg': { 
        '$exists':true
     },
     'history.content.read_processed': { 
        '$exists':true
     },
     'history.content.read_processed': false
 },
 {'history.$':1})
```

I read, that the raw-query doesn't support projections and that one should use `.only()` instead. But the problem here is, that it returns all the empty documents also…

Any advice?

Edit: Here are my models and a sample document:

```
class Subscriber(Document):
    service = StringField()
    history = EmbeddedDocumentListField('SubscriberHistory')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service


class SubscriberHistory(EmbeddedDocument):
    action = StringField()
    content = DictField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.action
```

And the sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e60b0c525fd2037e8dd31"),
    "service" : "foo",
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "outbound",
            "content" : {
                "read_processed" : false,
                "message_data" : {
                    "text" : "w00t?"
                },
                "read_process_msg" : {
                    "$ref" : "bots_messages",
                    "$id" : ObjectId("57a6529dc525fd8066ee25b3")
                }
            },
            "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-06T21:12:00.986Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can we see your document? Also `'history.content.read_processed': {'$exists':true}` is redundant.

Comment: @Styvane: see edit!